# MySQL shell cannot connect to MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a MySQL docker image running on Windows. I created it like this

```
docker pull mysql
docker run --name localmysql -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=r00t -d MySQL
```

and docker ps returns the ports as

```
33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp
```

When I go into MySQL shell and try to connect, I get an error. This is how I connect

```
\c -h localhost -P 3307 -u root -p r00t
```

If I am connecting wrongly, how should I connect in MySQL shell and should it work? Is there anything in my docker setup that would stop the connection working?

Comment: What error do you get?  The MySQL tooling can treat `localhost` as a signal to use a local socket instead of resolving it as a host name; does using `-h 127.0.0.1` instead make a difference?

Comment: I got it to work from the command line using "mysqlsh --sql --uri=root@localhost -P 3307 --password=r00t" but before, I was in the shell and it was failing. So what is the in-shell equivalent?